# If statement in data from DynamoDB to display divs for specific values

Tags: html, css, amazon-dynamodb

I am reading data from a DynamoDB table. I want to display a div if the output value is a certain value and display another div if the output value is another value.

For example, I want to show `<div class="green"></div>` if the output value is N and `<div class="red"></div>` if the output value is A

My DynamoDB script is given below

```
<script>
    AWS.config.update({
      region: "us-west-2",
      endpoint: 'https://dynamodb.us-west-2.amazonaws.com',
      accessKeyId: "Fakeaccesskey",
      secretAccessKey: "Fakeaccesskey"
    });

    var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

    function readItemhum() {
        var table = "Latest_Log";
        var GWID = "BB00000002";
        var ID = "AA00000018";

        var params = {
            TableName: table,
            Key:{
                "GWID": GWID,
                "ID": ID
            },
               "ProjectionExpression": "Hum"
        };
        docClient.get(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                document.getElementById('hum').innerHTML = "Unable to read item: " + "\n" + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2);
            } else {
                document.getElementById('hum').innerHTML = data.Item.Hum + "%";

            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<span id= "hum"></span>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is the problem you are facing to achieve this?

Comment: @ArMD I do not know what code to insert and where.